# Neo4j Spatial server error 500 when adding nodes to layer

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I am using the Spatial plugin for Neo4j 2.2.2 and have managed to create a spatial index by following the guide http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/#spatial-layers.

```
:POST   http://localhost:7475/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer
{
  "layer" : "geom",
  "lat" : "lat",
  "lon" : "lon"
} 

:POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/
{
  "name" : "geom",
  "config" : {
    "provider" : "spatial",
    "geometry_type" : "point",
    "lat" : "lat",
    "lon" : "lon"
  }
}
```

I have pre-existing unconnected nodes with multiple labels 'DB_2' and 'Address' and properties 'name', 'lon' and 'lat', when I try to add these nodes to the spatial index I get an error but if I create a node without any labels and just 'lon' and 'lat' properties it seems to work without any errors.

```
:POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer
{
  "layer" : "geom",
  "node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/{id}"
}

500 Internal Server Error
==> {
==>   "message" : "Error adding nodes to layer geom",
==>   "exception" : "RuntimeException",
==>   "fullname" : "java.lang.RuntimeException",
==>   "stackTrace" : [ "org.neo4j.gis.spatial.server.plugin.SpatialPlugin.addNodeToLayer(SpatialPlugin. java:108)","java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)",                        "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)","org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)","org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)","java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)","org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)","org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)","java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ],
==>   "cause" : {
==>     "exception" : "ClassCastException",
==>     "fullname" : "java.lang.ClassCastException",
==>     "stackTrace" : [ "org.neo4j.gis.spatial.encoders.SimplePointEncoder.decodeGeometry(SimplePointEncoder.java:63)", "   "org.neo4j.gis.spatial.DefaultLayer.add(DefaultLayer.java:77)", "org.neo4j.gis.spatial.server.plugin.SpatialPlugin.addNodeToLayer(SpatialPlugin.java:102)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ],
==>     "message" : "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number",
==>     "errors" : [ {
==>       "code" : "Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure",
==>       "stackTrace" : "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number\r\n\tat org.neo4j.gis.spatial.encoders.SimplePointEncoder.decodeGeometry(SimplePointEncoder.java:63)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.gis.spatial.DefaultLayer.add(DefaultLayer.java:77)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.gis.spatial.server.plugin.SpatialPlugin.addNodeToLayer(SpatialPlugin.java:102)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\n",
==>       "message" : "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number"
==>     } ]
==>   },
==>   "errors" : [ {
==>     "code" : "Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure",
==>     "stackTrace" : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error adding nodes to layer geom\r\n\tat org.neo4j.gis.spatial.server.plugin.SpatialPlugin.addNodeToLayer(SpatialPlugin.java:108)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number\r\n\tat org.neo4j.gis.spatial.encoders.SimplePointEncoder.decodeGeometry(SimplePointEncoder.java:63)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.gis.spatial.DefaultLayer.add(DefaultLayer.java:77)\r\n\tat                                          org.neo4j.gis.spatial.server.plugin.SpatialPlugin.addNodeToLayer(SpatialPlugin.java:102)\r\n\t... 49 more\r\n",
 ==>     "message" : "Error adding nodes to layer geom"
 ==>   } ]
 ==> }
```

I not sure if it has anything to do with my node labels or properties as I can't find any indication from the guide or other examples suggesting that this could be a problem.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Just a guess based on the error message ` "message" : "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number"` - how are the `lat` and `lon` properties stored on the nodes? As strings or doubles?

Comment: Yes I have just realised I had stored some of my lat and lon as strings! thank you, working perfectly now(: